# How can I import large-size videos into Android Studio?

Tags: android, file, import

When I write a project and want to play a video in my application, once I import a large video like 100Mb, the software will report an error says

> "Execution failed for task ':app:processInstantRunDebugResourcesApk'"

. It will be alright if I import a video like 20Mb. What should I do to solve this problem if I really want to use large video?

I ready update my Android Studio into the latest version as well as my `gradle` and `Kotlin`.

```
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException 
    at
com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$2.invoke(BuildElements.kt:133)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$2.invoke(BuildElements.kt:110)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt$onEach$1.invoke(_Sequences.kt:1317)
    at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:172)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.calcNext(Sequences.kt:132)
    at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:156)
    at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:176)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toCollection(_Sequences.kt:698)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toMutableList(_Sequences.kt:728)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toList(_Sequences.kt:719)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler.transform(BuildElements.kt:140)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler.into(BuildElements.kt:115)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElementActionScheduler.into(BuildElementActionScheduler.kt:32)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.InstantRunResourcesApkBuilder.doFullTaskAction(InstantRunResourcesApkBuilder.java:163)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:705)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:672)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$4.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:338)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:327)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:312)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:28)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:133)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.lambda$execute$5(CacheStep.java:83)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.PrepareCachingStep.execute(PrepareCachingStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:23)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:95)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:88)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveIncrementalChangesTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveIncrementalChangesTaskExecuter.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:598)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForAllTasks(WaitableExecutor.java:215)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler.transform(BuildElements.kt:125)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
    at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:110)
    at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.toByteArray(ByteStreams.java:166)
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.StoredEntry.read(StoredEntry.java:291)
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension.onZipEntryOutput(SigningExtension.java:251)
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension.access$400(SigningExtension.java:53)
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension$1.lambda$added$0(SigningExtension.java:160)
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.sign.SigningExtension$1$$Lambda$411/1640503201.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.notify(ZFile.java:2154)
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.addToEntries(ZFile.java:1795)
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.processAllReadyEntries(ZFile.java:1736)
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.add(ZFile.java:1607)
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zip.ZFile.mergeFrom(ZFile.java:1959)
    at com.android.tools.build.apkzlib.zfile.ApkZFileCreator.writeZip(ApkZFileCreator.java:115)
    at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.IncrementalPackager.updateFiles(IncrementalPackager.java:206)
    at com.android.builder.internal.packaging.IncrementalPackager.updateAndroidResources(IncrementalPackager.java:255)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.packageCodeSplitApk(AndroidBuilder.java:1466)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.InstantRunResourcesApkBuilder.lambda$doFullTaskAction$1(InstantRunResourcesApkBuilder.java:147)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.InstantRunResourcesApkBuilder$$Lambda$380/528460571.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.call(BuildElements.kt:121)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildElements$ExecutorBasedScheduler$transform$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.call(BuildElements.kt:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? If you want a static video in the app compress it. Or make an app that will play any video present in the phone.

Comment: How you are importing video?

Comment: @nimi0112 well I just want to import a large video and don't want to compress. How can I import it?

Comment: @ChetanShelake Just copy and paste it into the raw file

Comment: @FrankSmith It is not proper way for large videos. You should upload video to server then show it by url through VideoView, or use library for buffering like ExoPlayer. If you don't have server then simply use firebase storage to upload video.